# Make DIV 100% height of grandparent, while also stretching grandparent's width

Tags: html, css

I have some DIVs in the following structure:

```
<div id="R">
    <div id="GA"></div>
    <div id="GP">
        <div id="P">
            <div id="C"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**R** has `display:flex`, `flex-direction:row`, and `align-items:stretch`. It also occupies all the screen space available, except for a nav menu at the left and a title bar at the top. **GA** is set to `flex-grow:1`, and **GP** to `flex-grow:0`. Both combined occupy all height and width of **R**. **P** has no notable styling, but I can't add any CSS to it because of X reason(*) (and it's actually not one, but a bunch of nested DIVs with, again, no relevant styling). **C** has a bunch of stuff inside that give it its width, but its height is smaller that **GP**'s. No element has its height or width set with actual numbers.

Now comes the problem. I need **C** to have 100% the height of **GP**, but **GP**'s width needs to be stretched by **C**.

EDIT: [jsfiddle of an example](https://jsfiddle.net/ro_sjda42/ztjx4q6u/).

This could be done by applying styling to `DIV#GA > DIV` forcing **P** to fill the height of **GP**, which makes stretching **C** vertically a trivial matter. But I want to know if there's a way to do it by only styling **GP** and **C**.

Been trying for a few hours and nothing seems to work.

(*) **C** is a component treated by the development tool I'm using as separate object from the actual page. Main page only has the structure down to **GP**. When building the proyect, the tool places some DIVs inside **GP** and then it puts the component (**C**) inside those. **P** ends up having its own classes and ids which I can't change. Those are also used by other elements (in the same page for classes, and others for ids) so I can't target them with my own CSS without touching the other elements.

Comment: Instead of explaining which HTML elements have which CSS attributes, why not just post the CSS code too? You can even post a working code example for us to test with. This helps us help you.

Comment: Welcome at SO, and Chris is right: we're coders (strike that, 'developers') and don't read (complicated) text on SO. You'd better post a [reprex]. Like with an image, worth more than a 1000 words.... And usually the error is in the CSS, so post it.

Comment: Thanks for reading! The tool works with .NET and the resulting files are .cs. Also it's not just one since it separates those into modules when using components. I could post the resulting dom tree and the css files, but that's around 70KB of text just for the html. Kinda excessive for 8 lines of relevant code. I can still try and create an example.

Comment: @RenevanderLende just read the page about the minimal reproducible example, I'll try and make a simple example of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Generally speaking the logic would be: `.grandpa { some-width: either fixed or relative }` then `.parent { width: 100% }` (of `.gp`) and `.child { width: 100% }` (of `.p`, which is 100% of `.gp`). You need to keep track of the spacing you are using (depending on the `box-sizing` used => preferred = `border-box`, but CSS default = `content-box` [w3schools: CSS box-sizing Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp))

Comment: @RenevanderLende That would work, but I can't touch the styling of P (.parent) to add the `width: 100%`. Also, there's an example in the post now which I hope helps to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you cannot modify **GP** classes, but that does not mean you cannot override them. Example: Tool adds class '.gp-styling{ color: some-color } ' you can add CSS `{ .gp-styling: some-other-color }`. Works for anything, just need to make sure your code is last inside the `<head>`. Unless....you are not **allowed** (by some project-manager) to change the values....

Comment: @RenevanderLende I can modify GP but not P. And the problem with adding my own styling to P is that it would also apply to other instances of components since they use the same classes. Targeting the id is also not an option since it's generated by the tool in sequence for all components in the page and any changes would result in another id being used for P. I CAN target P by using the child of GP selector, but I wanted to know if there was another way without touching P.

Comment: Ok, `#P`, little oversight on my part. Here's the thing: in your example you use `#P` which addresses a unique ID. So from my point of view any CSS using `#P` is unique to that specific element, thusly overridable. See the importance of posting 'original' code? BTW, I'm at 4:00am, quitting time for today....

Comment: @RenevanderLende Ah, I see how that can be confusing, sorry about that. And thank you for your time. Gonna give up myself for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *dry* explanation:

- make **GP** `display: flex`, because its child elements will be stretched due to CSS default `align-items: stretch`
- this will stretch **P** to **GP** flexbox row height independed of `flex-grow` (= default: 0, as FBL parent is default 'row', a childs' `flex-grow` affects only the stretching of its **width**) => **P** height = **GP** height
- Make **C** `height: 100%` as **P** now has a height **C** can reference (namely the height of **GP**). => **C** `height: 100%` = height **P** = height **GP**
- **GP** width has to be **C** width dependend. As we don't know what **P** does, **C** cannot have a percentage width (which is parent depended), so either give **C** a viewport dependend unit vw/vh/vmin/vmax, or calc(...) a width, etc. or a fixed unit. In the snippet `.C { width: 10vw; }`
- This will make **C** force its width upon **P** and, because of the `align-items` of **GP**, also upon **GP**

(...and you thought you were cryptic...)

Fortunately the snippet is heavily commented. BTW, I added some extra HTML/CSS to get something resembling a 'live' page. Also: I changed the IDs into classes.

```css
.cardList { /* list of ... cards */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1); padding-top: 1rem
}
.card { /* some main container holding an R */
    position: relative; /* stacking context for .R */

    width: 40vw; /* some arbitrary width/height/spacing */
    height: calc(0.5265 * 40vw);
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}


.R {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;

  top   : 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left  : 0;
  right : 0;

/*  align-items: stretch; /* REMOVE, flex default */
}

.GA {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

.GP {
/*  flex-grow: 0; /* REMOVE, flex default */

  /* ADD, make GP a flex-container so it has 'align-items: stretch'
          this will stretch P giving C a height it can reference
  */
  display: flex;

  background-color: red;
  padding: 15px;

  /* ADD [optional], but GP size will be limited by R,
     so, what to do when it overflows? Right, scrollbars (or ellipses..., w.e.)
     And excess content of C has to go somewhere as its height is GP depended
  */
  overflow: auto;
}

.P { /* CAN'T CHANGE THIS */ }

.C {

  /* ADD, with some test value */
  width: 10vw;
  /* Will force GP width as P has default 'width: auto; height: auto'.
     Has to be a 'hard' (relative or px) width to force P and therefore GP,
     percentages won't work as that would be based on parent */

  height: 100%;
  /* GP is flex with default 'align-items: stretch'
     this will stretch P
     if P is 'stretched' then C has a reference size, so it can go 100%
     which is full size of GP (minus GP padding, etc...)
  */


  background-color: yellow;
}

.some-content {
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}


/**************************************/
/* my personal preferred global rules */
/**************************************/
html,body               { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; max-width: 100% }
*::before,*::after, *   { box-sizing: inherit }
body                    { margin: 0 }
/*

    All math reference:  https://www.mathsisfun.com/equation_of_line.html

*/
/* responsive base font size using y = mx + b */
html   { font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem) } /* (320,14)(1280,20) */

[band] { display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap; 
         justify-content: center; align-content: center; align-items: center }

body[padded="1"],
body[padded="0"] [band*="padded"] {
/*
    responsive page padding
    and responsive band padding (same as responsive page padding, but at band level)
    p1(320,32) p2(1920, 72) => 0.025x + 24
    p3(320, 8) p4(1920,320) => 0.195x - 54.4 

    'Band padding' is only active when 'page padding' is off 
*/
    padding: calc( 2.5vh + 24px) calc(19.5vw - 54.4px);
}
/* for debugging */
[outlines="1"] * { outline: 1px dashed }
```

```html
<body outlines="1" padded="1">
<div class="cardList" band>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="R">
          <div class="GA"></div>
          <div class="GP">
            <div class="P"> <!-- CAN'T CHANGE THIS ELEMENT-->
              <div class="C">
                <div class="some-content">
                </div> <!-- PACEHOLDER FOR CONTENT-->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="R">
          <div class="GA"></div>
          <div class="GP">
            <div class="P"> <!-- CAN'T CHANGE THIS ELEMENT-->
              <div class="C">
                <div class="some-content">
                </div> <!-- PACEHOLDER FOR CONTENT-->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You wonderful man/woman. That's exactly what I was lookin for! Never thought of using `align-items: stretch;` with the right `flex-direction` on **GP** to force **P** to take 100% of it's height. Thanks for coming back, and for the solution!

Comment: @thexbuttonisntworking Last time I checked, I was male (dunno about now). Will update the answer and remove the 'initial... etc' only. Anyway, maybe next time just post the code in the snippet instead of a Fiddle and summerize your problem (code next to text is easier to read). It was (and will be for others) rather hard to read... Glad to been of help, though!